# Xamarin Android Emulator Failed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I try to install the Xamarin Android Emulator v27.3.9  it fails to installed.

> Is there anyway around this? anything I can do it fix this

[image]

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: I just get the message installing Android emulator 27.3.9 failed

Comment: Well, it’s hard to say where the problem is.You can first check if there is windows firewall.

Comment: I would first check if from Visual Studio installer there is an updated version. I had myself issues with android emulator until the update I got a couple of days ago.The emulator version on my system now is stating 29.3.0